# Accessing AzureKeyVault

Tags: c#, azure-keyvault

I just created my first Azure Key Vault. Yea!! Now I want to access the secrets in the vault. The online tutorial or quick-start talks about setting up a service principle etc. I tried `az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "http://RonaldKevinBurtonServicePrinciple" --sdk-auth` as recommended but I get an error

```
Directory permission is needed for the current user to register the application. For how to configure, please refer 'https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal'. Original error: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

Rather than go down the rabbit-hole of finding out what permission I need an why, I would like to understand some basics. First, when the Key Vault is created there is a policy assigned to it it seems that this policy is assigned to me.
[screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zacK2.png)
What is this default policy? Do I need to add a service principle (has one already been generated for me)? Anyone have tips for accessing the Key Vault secrets over and above what is mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net-v3).?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation provided in the error message? It explicitly answers your question almost immediately.

Comment: I was not sure how to add directory permission. I don't know what directory permission is. I created this key vault so I am not sure what additional permissions are required.

Answer (score 1):

> Directory permission is needed for the current user to register the
> application.

According to your error message, your user does not have  permission to register the application, so you need to assign  user the permission to register  application.

Log in to the Azure portal as a tenant administrator, find **Users**>**User settings**, find **App registration**, and set it to **Yes**.

[image]

> when the Key Vault is created there is a policy assigned to it it
> seems that this policy is assigned to me.  What is this
> default policy?

When you create a key vault, you need to grant your application proper access to the Key Vault. By default, the current access policy is the administrator account you created the Key Vault.

> Do I need to add a service principle (has one already
> been generated for me)?

Yes, you need to create a service principal based on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net-v3#create-a-resource-group-and-key-vault).

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you this will get me started. First I created this Key Vault with my own account and that account is under a corporate account. So when I log in I login in the corporate domain. I don't have permission to manage any of the corporate key vaults. But I created this Key Vault and as I understand it should be able to administer it. Right?

Comment: @KevinBurton  Yes!